# SQL trigger insert or update with same table avoid recursive

Tags: sql-server, recursion, triggers

I am SQL GUI kind of person and have less experience writing trigger.  I did some searching and came up the following code.  I cannot make any database level parameter change and cannot alter the table scheme.  A column called Myvalue will be numbers but some it shows decimal value.  My goal is to make sure the value of the column Myvalue is an integer when insert or update.  If a decimal value is updated or inserted, the trigger will fire and remove the decimal value.  Will the following code do the job?  Do I need to use the trigger_nestlevel command to avoid recursion?  How can I test to make sure the trigger run once even with multiple rows on insert or update?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS 'Mytrigger'  
CREATE TRIGGER ON Table1  
AFTER insert, update  
AS  
BEGIN  
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(OBJECT_ID('Mytrigger')) <= 1  
    BEGIN  
        set nocount on  
        UPDATE Mytable set Myvalue=substring(Myvalue,0,charindex('.',Myvalue))  
        FROM Mytable t  
        inner join inserted i on i.Myvalue like '%.%'  
    END    
END
```

Comment: What do you mean it will show as a decimal value? What is the datatype of  `myvalue` on the table?

Comment: myvalue datatype is nvarchar(2000).  For example, the value always be numbers like 456 or 123 or 435.67.  If any value in myvalue is 435.67, the trigger will fire and change the value 435.67 to 435